# Custom radio selector not functioning

Tags: html, css, radio-button, selector

I've created this custom radio selector for my site and the first radio selector is working but the 2nd field isn't selecting. Is there another class that I need to create or have each input named a different ID so they don't conflict with one another? I'm trying to create multiple options for a customer to select an option.

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label+input[type=radio]+label {
  border-left: solid 3px #444;
}

.radio-group {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <input type="radio" id="lessthan6months" name="timeline"><label for="lessthan6months">6 mo</label>
  <input type="radio" id="6to12months" name="timeline"><label for="6to12months">6-12 mo</label>
  <input type="radio" id="12to24months" name="timeline"><label for="12to24months">12-24 mo</label>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>

<div class="radio-group">
  <input type="radio" id="tradein_y" name="tradein" value="Yes"><label for="trade in yes">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tradein_n" name="tradein" value="No"><label for="trade in no">No</label>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` of the `label` content has to match the `id` of the `input`.

This will work, like this:

```css
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: none;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

label+input[type=radio]+label {
  border-left: solid 3px #444;
}

.radio-group {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <input type="radio" id="lessthan6months" name="timeline"><label for="lessthan6months">6 mo</label>
  <input type="radio" id="6to12months" name="timeline"><label for="6to12months">6-12 mo</label>
  <input type="radio" id="12to24months" name="timeline"><label for="12to24months">12-24 mo</label>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>

<div class="radio-group">
  <input type="radio" id="tradein_y" name="tradein" value="Yes"><label for="tradein_y">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" id="tradein_n" name="tradein" value="No"><label for="tradein_n">No</label>
  <div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is what I was missing, thank you for taking a look at this

Comment: You're welcome. ;-) Most of the time the most obvious is to take a look at the working part of the code and compare it to the not working one.